# Staging or landing on Azure

Tags: azure, etl, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am performing ETL in Azure Data Factory and I just wanted to confirm my understanding of it before going further. Please find the image attached below.

[image]

I am collecting data from multiple source and storing in Azure Blob Storage then perform Transformation and Loading. What I am confused about is that whether Azure Blob Storage is a landing or staging area here in my case. Some people use these terms interchangeably and couldn't understand the fine line between these two terms.

Also, can anyone explain me which part is Extract, Transform and Load is. In my understating, collecting the data from multiple source and store into Azure Blob Storage is Extracting, Azure Data Factory is Transformation and copying the transformed data into Azure Database is Loading. Am i correct or is there something I am misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am confused about is that whether Azure Blob Storage is a
>   landing or staging area here in my case.

In your case, Azure Blob Storage is both landing area and staging area. Landing area means a area collecting data from different places. Staing area means it only save data for a little time, staging data should be deleted during ETL process.

> Also, can anyone explain me which part is Extract, Transform and Load
>   is.

Copy Activity is a typical technology based on ETL. If only talking about the Copy Activity of Azure Data Factory, after you specify the copy source, the ADF will perform copy activities based on this, this is 'extract'. The part of the ADF that transfers data to the specified Sink according to your settings, this is 'Load', and the details of the copy behavior is 'Transform'. If you look at your entire process, you collect data to blob storage is also 'Extract'.